# Where are the select query values stored temporarily and how to get each value separately

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure with a `SELECT` statement that outputs one row. It is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateCustomer]
...

INSERT INTO Customers values(, , , ,)
SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, LastNam.....
INSERT Roles values(, , , .....
```

This selects the newly stored values back from the `Customers` table. The second insert uses  the new  `CustomerID` to insert a new row to the `Roles` table.

Is there a way to just get the `customerID` from the above select statement without querying again for the CustomerID?

I have tried to declare a variable and do it like this:

```
SELECT takenCustomerID = CustomerID, FirstName, LastNam....(rest of query statement)
```

But I have to declare all the variables and do it this way:

```
SELECT takenCustomerID, takenFirstName, takenLastNa... = CustomerID, FirstName, LastNam... (rest of query statement)
```

But, I think this is bad because it wastes lot of memory on the server side.

**So, is there an easy way of getting individual values right away without declaring all the  variables in the select statement, such as an inbuilt TEMP-like variable where I can call TEMP("customerID") and get that value?**

Also, **Can there be more than one SELECT statement in a stored procedure? How can we get the select values from the select statement we want?**

I am asking more out of curiosity because I already know a way to get the value. I just want to know if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Do you *have to* do a separate `SELECT` (i.e. are you using the values again later on in the SP?)? If not, you can do `INSERT INTO Roles SELECT ... FROM ...` instead.

Comment: So which is it, SQL Server or MySql? The answers will be completely different depending on your DBMS.

Comment: @Ic: I want all the values that I have inserted to return back and to insert a role to the roles table with the GUID that I am getting from the select query

Comment: @ErikE I am using sql server 2008

Comment: What data type is your CustomerID and how is it getting created? Is it a uniqueidentifier? Are you creating it implicitly by a default or using `newid()` or what?

Comment: @ErikE I am not using newid by default. Because I have to insert some old record to the table. So I am declaring an id as uniqueidentifier and initialize it with newID() and include the value in the insert statement.

Comment: If you have the `newid` in a variable in advance, what is the problem? You already have the value?

Comment: Yes, I could do it easily too, But there is another auto generated Id and that has to be taken and used it in other statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accessing Inserted Values**

It is simple. Use the `OUTPUT` clause to return the values you just created.

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (
   CustomerID uniqueidentifier,
   FirstName varchar(100),
   LastName varchar(100)
);

INSERT dbo.Customers 
OUTPUT Inserted.*
INTO @Customers
SELECT newsequentialid(), @FirstName, @LastName, ...;
-- now you have all the values of the new row in the `@Customers` table variable.
```

Then you can do this:

```
INSERT dbo.Roles
SELECT
   CustomerID,
   @OtherValue,
   @AnotherValue,
   AnyotherColumnFrom@Customers
FROM @Customers;
```

If you have no further use for the values from the inserted Customer row, you could even do away with the table variable and just OUTPUT directly into the Roles table, assuming that all the values that go into that come from variables.

The `OUTPUT` clause gives access to the inserted values using the special meta-table `Inserted`. However, you can use variables and expressions with constants as well.

The good thing about using this method is that you can handle many inserted rows at once. If you are inserting only one row, you need only the `CustomerID` afterward, and you need to use it more than once, then instead do it this way:

```
DECLARE @CustomerID uniqueidentifier = newsequentialid();
INSERT @Customer VALUES (@CustomerID, ...);
INSERT @Roles VALUES (..., @CustomerID ...);
```

By creating the GUID in advance, you don't need to get it back out of the table. By the way, `newsequentialid()` is probably superior to `newid()` if it is the clustered index (which is probably true), because you will avoid the page splits that `newid` would cause.

**Returning Multiple Result Sets**

This is always possible. Whatever means you are using to query will have a method that advances your data access object to the next recordset. If you're using a `DataReader` then look into the `NextResult` method. In Classic ADO, recordsets have a `NextRecordset` method.

Comment: I guess Marc's post helped more? :)

Comment: Wow, Thanks,, I will use newsequentialid(). And I will look in to Data reader.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you redirect it manually to a table, the `SELECT` will go only to the output stream, so no: you can't automatically access values from a previous select.

You *might* just be looking for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

```
declare @id int

insert ....
values (...)

set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

In the general case of DML, another candidate is the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

For more general composite selects based on existing selects, a table-variable may help:

```
declare @foo table (id int not null, name nvarchar(100) not null) // etc

insert @foo (id, name)
select id, name from Foo where ...

select * from @foo // for output

// but we still have the @foo data available for subsequent query

... // more TSQL here
```

With multiple select statements, it depends entirely on what API you are using; however, the raw ADO.NET API here is `IDataReader`, which has the `NextResult()` method. Typical usage for multi-grid would be:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    do {
        while(reader.Read()) {
          // i.e. for each row in this grid
          ...
        }
    } while (reader.NextResult()); // <== for each grid
}
```

Note the difference between `while(...) {...}` and `do {...} while(...)` here is because you **automatically** start in the first grid, but you need to progress to the first **row** in that grid manually.